# Laravel 4 : Call to a member function move() on a non-object with when creating a new file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have an webb app where user fills up the form and based upon that entry a new file has to be created.

Here are the code for store function in mycontroller:

```
public function store()
{

    $input = Input::only('name', 'location', 'description', 'phrase');
    $this->homepageForm->validate($input);

    $homoepage = Homepage::create($input);
    $homoepage->save();

    $name = Input::get('name');

    $destination = app_path()."/views/uploads";

    $ext = "blade.php";

    $filename = str_random(6).'.'.$ext;

   $file = $name->move($destination, $filename);
    if($file)
   {
       echo 'good';
   }

  //return Redirect::home();
}
```

This is one of the input field in the form where user will enter a name of the location

```
   $name = Input::get('name');
```

and this name will be used as a file name with extension. And I want to create this file and save into uploads folder.

The file name and destination are correct. I have verified it. But when I want to move it to uploads folder, it just throws an error. 
Thanks!!

Comment: You haven't opened your file anywhere..

Comment: Hi, I followed http://laravel.com/docs/requests. I don't know why I need to open the file here. Excuse me, I am completely new to file handling and been learning laravel for few days. Could you please, guide me ? Thanks!!

Comment: no worries, have a look at my answer... hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not creating the file at the moment... why not just create it straight into the uploads folder?

```
// added a / at the end here:
$destination = app_path()."/views/uploads/";
$ext = "blade.php";

$file = $destination . str_random(6).'.'.$ext;

// creates an empty file
$f = fopen($file, 'w');
fclose($f);

if(File::exists($file))
{
    echo 'good';
}
```

Not sure if you have considered this, but you are creating this file with a random name... are you recording that name somewhere?  might be hard to find later if not!!  :)

Comment: Hi, I must be somewhere near to the answer with the help of your above answer. But I don't see file created inside uploads folder.

Comment: yes it does echo good!! But no file created. Since, I have defined the $destination, I should be able to see the file in the destination right? The uploads folder is empty.

Comment: Does the server have `write` permissions in the `uploads` directory?

Comment: That was quite strange. It worked now. Thanks mate ;). Really appreciate for your time ;)

Comment: excellent!  I've also updated the `if` to check that the file exists using Laravel's methods.

Comment: I salute you and your time and help ;) It gives a beginner like me a strength to learn. I am happy here.

Answer (score 4):

To fix this you need to:

```
Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar', 'files' => true))
```

Or

```
<form method="post" action="{{ URL::route('your-route') }}" 
enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: my problem was that I forgot to include `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

replace `$name = Input::get('name');` By:

```
$name = Input::file('name');
```

Comment: Hi, its not working. I am not uploading any file here. I will be creating completely a new file inside uploads folder and name of the file will be the name of the input field. The contents of the file will be description provided in the form.